# VIM: Unbind default F4 key / set F4 to plugin function

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

The plugin I'm using has a bind for F4 that I put into .vimrc:

```
nmap <F4> <Plug>(plugin-name)
```

But, it doesn't seem to take effect; right now, when I press F4, it does the Vim default of changing the case of the word under the cursor.

How do I:

1. Unbind F4 from Vim's default
2. Check that the nmap  iscorrectly set?

When I do :map, I see:

```
n  <F4>          <Plug>(plugin-name)
```

Which appears to have correctly set F4.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: try ``noremap`` instead of ``nmap``.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Unbind F4 from Vim's default

```
:nunmap <F4>
```

> Check that the nmap iscorrectly set ?

```
:map
```

For showing mappings in normal-visual-operator modes

```
:map!
```

For showing mappings in command-insert modes

---

If you encounter some problems during the mapping of function keys, use the map arguments `<special>` :

```
nmap <special> <F4> <Plug>(plugin-name)
```